# Treeview After Label Edit Event not called While using text box to limit Treeview Node Name up to 60 characters

Tags: c#, winforms

Here i am using TextBox to limit Node Name Up to 60 Characters which causing problem that After label edit event not get Fired

```
/// <summary>
/// This event use to restrict user input up to 60 Characters.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void tvFolders_BeforeLabelEdit(object sender, NodeExLabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    txtFolderName.MaxLength = 60;
    e.CancelEdit = true;
    TreeNodeEx selectedNode = tvFolders.SelectedNode;
    txtFolderName.Visible = true;
    e.Node.Text =txtFolderName.Text = selectedNode.Text;
    txtFolderName.SelectAll();
    txtFolderName.BringToFront();
    txtFolderName.Left = tvFolders.Left + selectedNode.Bounds.Left;
    txtFolderName.Top = tvFolders.Top + selectedNode.Bounds.Top;
    txtFolderName.Focus()
}
```

Below event is not called which contain my Business Logic which is not getting fired if I am using `TextBox` to limit user input up to 60 characters

```
private void tvFolders_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, Framework.Utilities.Controls.ExtendedTreeView.NodeExLabelEditEventArgs e)
{       
    if(e.Label.Length >60)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter Less than 60 Characters in folder name.", "New Folder", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        e.CancelEdit = true;
        this.tvFolders.SelectedNode = e.Node;               
    }           
    else if(IsDuplicateFolderName(e.Node, e.Label, (DataRowView)e.Node.DataRow))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This folder name already exists. Please provide a new name.", "New Folder", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        e.CancelEdit = true;
        this.tvFolders.SelectedNode = e.Node;       
        SaveNewNode(e, true);
    }
    else if(e.Label.Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Folder name cannot be empty", "New Folder", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        e.CancelEdit = true;
        this.tvFolders.SelectedNode = e.Node;               
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course AfterLabelEdit() doesn't get fired, you **cancelled** the edit in BeforeLabelEdit().  How can you have an "after" edit when NO edit took place?

```
        private void tvFolders_BeforeLabelEdit(object sender, NodeExLabelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            // ...
            e.CancelEdit = true;
```

Put the AfterLabelEdit() logic (it will need changing) in its own method and fire it from an event associated with your TextBox `txtFolderName`.

Comment: Is there is any way to call this event from Before Label Edit.?When i used e.CancelEdit = false; in before edit event after label edit event get fired but my restriction on user input was no more.

Comment: How do you know when the "edit" is complete when using the TextBox?  Wire up your desired EVENT from the TextBox, then place your logic in there.  The AfterLabelEdit() event doesn't apply since you cancelled it in BeforeLabelEdit().  Instead, you'll need to track what node is being edited and then manually update that node with the new value from the TextBox event that you wire up.

Comment: Is it possible to restrict Label edit up to 60 characters without using Text box?

Answer (score 1):

@Idle already explained why this doesn't work.  Setting the text limit on the edit control that TreeView creates is quite possible, Winforms is infinitely extensible by using the native Windows api.  It is the kind of code that Petzold shows how to write in his book "Programming Windows".  Make it look like this:

```
    private void treeView1_BeforeLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e) {
        IntPtr edit = SendMessage(treeView1.Handle, TVM_GETEDITCONTROL, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        SendMessage(edit, EM_SETLIMITTEXT, (IntPtr)60, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    private static int TVM_GETEDITCONTROL = 0x1100 + 15;
    private static int EM_SETLIMITTEXT = 0x00c5;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
```

Comment: I tested this before I posted, Petzold would agree it works.  Don't just paste the code, make sure that the BeforeLabelEdit event is registered and that the event handler runs.  And test it with, say, (IntPtr)5 instead of 60 so you can easily see the limit.

Comment: Before label edit event fired in that i just put your code ans change it like(IntPtr)5  but it is not limiting the user input on label?

Comment: The code above works for me as well.  Note from the docs, however: "The EM_SETLIMITTEXT message limits only the text the user can enter. It does not affect any text already in the edit control when the message is sent, nor does it affect the length of the text copied to the edit control by the WM_SETTEXT message."  Is the Node Text starting out longer than 60 characters?